# filtering cumbersome list of objects with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a cumbersome list of objects. The count is about 25.837.
once I want to filter my object with such this linq expression

```
        underManagementPersonList.OrderByDescending(x => x.BarCode).Where(x => x.CardNum.Contains("0480286000") || x.BarCode.Contains("0480286000") || x.PersonName.Contains("0480286000")).Skip(pageIndex).ToList();   Evaluation timed out    System.Collections.Generic.List<GTS.Clock.Model.MonthlyReport.UnderManagementPerson>
```

I get this error

> Evaluation timed out

ALthogh there is no such problem with fewer items like below which jusk I get 100 items

```
underManagementPersonList.Take(100).OrderByDescending(x => x.BarCode).Where(x => x.CardNum.Contains("0480286000") || x.BarCode.Contains("0480286000") || x.PersonName.Contains("0480286000")).Skip(pageIndex).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Is this LINQ 2 objects or do you work with a databse?

Comment: Try filtering first then sorting. The sorting is by far the most time consuming thing in your code. Not sure if it'll solve your issue but there is no reason to sort your collection and then throw them all away.

Comment: Since where cuts down on the number of objects orderbydescending has to deal with, probably significantly, I'd recommend trying putting where before orderbydescending.

Comment: @SomeBody it is LINQ to objects

Comment: @Loocid In my case I have to sort them at first place .I kind of mimic ROW_NUMBER() in sql server command.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I din't get you.Can you explain more please  ,though I can't cut it down .

Comment: using a simple class with the posted properties I cannot reproduce your problem. Could you post the class declaration?

Comment: @amirkian - Can you please post the class `GTS.Clock.Model.MonthlyReport.UnderManagementPerson` and what the exact error message is?

Comment: Is this backed by a database? Looking at it I think you need to be more decisive with your search term - 0480286000 is not a person name, and you should perhaps make barcode and card number searches equals, not contains. Inspect the search term and run a targeted search: if all numeric and 16 chars; cardnum. Else if All numeric; barcode. Else, person name

Comment: Put a Take of the page size in too, or just forget paging. If a human executes a search and gets 26000 items, splitting them into pages of 100 isn't going to help; noone is going to eyeball 260 pages(or if they do it's a bad solution; they know what they are looking for so give them better refinement tools). "More than 500 results; please refine your search"?

Comment: @CaiusJard I agree with you that there is a business problem here .by the way I can't change the business code becuse I just tuning a large query and I am not allowed to change business code unfortunatly.

Comment: Don't know what backend db, but you might get some improvement taking a `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = @x OR b = @x OR c = @x` and making it `SELECT * FROM t WHERE a = @x UNION SELECT * FROM t WHERE b = @x UNION SELECT * FROM t WHERE c = @x` - I know, you'd imagine they'd be the same, but past experience with SQLServer was that in some cases, it just wasnt parallelizing the query the same with OR, and the difference with UNION was pronounced

Comment: @amirkian - Please don't ignore my request.

Comment: @CaiusJard you are right ,insted of using or I used Union sql statment and the perfomance right now is much better that it was .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is simply a list of objects then the order is important - you can speed things up by placing your `.Where()` before your `.OrderByDescending()`

```
underManagementPersonList
    .Where(x => x.CardNum.Contains("0480286000")
        || x.BarCode.Contains("0480286000")
        || x.PersonName.Contains("0480286000"))
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.BarCode)
    .Skip(pageIndex)
    .ToList();
```

This still has the potentially expensive/slow string.Contains calls on as many as 3 times on 25,837 objects but at least you'll only be sorting the subset of objects which match your Where.

NOTE: Placing the Where before the `OrderByDescending` will produce the same set of objects in the same order - the difference is that as long as at least one of the objects is filtered out by your where then it will be faster - the smaller the set that matches your where the faster the orderby will be.

Comment: I still get Evaluation timed out.

Comment: @amirkian - Then there's a problem with the code that you haven't shown us. Please provide all of the relevant code.

Comment: @Enigmativity The relevand code is so sophesticated to share it here .Ultimatly I end up to do this with sql and get response then I have just one record.

Comment: @amirkian - It'd still be good to solve your original issue.